# Broken boot after increasing disk size

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, gparted

My ubuntu server will not boot after I increased the disk size.

I'm still very new to using/troubleshooting linux/ubuntu and im not entirely sure how I have managed to break the boot/grub so hopefully somebody can help me fix my issue and tell me where i went wrong.

Below is a summary of the actions taken so far;

Booted with live cd and used gparted to increase the disk size

Used lvmmanager on live cd to increase the filesystem size

Rebooted after and got "error unknown filesystem, grub rescue"

booted with live cd and used boot-repair - pastebin from boot-repair: http://paste.ubuntu.com/16763967/

My machine now boots to a black screen and does nothing.

## Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can still use GParted on either the LiveCD or Boot-Repair.
Then decrease fs size with the same tool on either LiveCD or Boot-Repair